# What is the difference between Bytes.toString(bytes) and bytes.toString()?

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I have an integer that is represented by array of bytes.

```
byte[] result = getResult();
resultInt1 = Integer.parseInt(Bytes.toString(result));//1               
resultInt2 = Integer.parseInt(result.toString());//2
```

In first way everything works fine, but in the second I catch NumberFormatException.

What is the difference between these two methods?

Comment: Just try `System.out.println(Bytes.toString(result));` and `System.out.println(result.toString());` and see for yourself. Would have been quicker than typing the question.

Comment: What does the Bytes#toString method do.  AFAICT, Bytes isn't part of standard java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays do not override `toString()`.

Therefore, `bytes.toString()` does not return anything meaningful; instead, it will return something like `[B@18c28a`.  (`[B` is the internal representation of an array of `byte`)